# Setting a variable in mounted but doesn't changes after the variable is set

Tags: vuejs2

What I want to do is save a value before it is changed.

```
mounted () {
    this.noneChangedResults = this.results;
  }
```

So that I can do this.

```
methods: {
    saveChanges(){
      this.$router.push({ name: "resultsAfterEdit", params: {newResults: this.results}});
    },
    exit(){
      console.log(this.noneChangedResults);
      this.$router.push({ name: "resultsAfterEdit", params: {newResults: this.noneChangedResults}});
    }
  },
```

This is done so that I dont save the new results on exit (when `exit()` is called)

`this.results` is manipulated with v-model

after `this.results` is changed so is `this.noneChangedResults`. I do not want this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that the object `this.noneChangedResults` is just referencing the other object `this.results`.

A simple fix is:

```
  mounted () {
    this.noneChangedResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.results));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe it's happening is that you're giving a reference of `results` to `noneChangedResults`, so when the first one changes the last one changes too because it is a reference to the first object.

To solve this and give `noneChangedResults` single ownership of it's data just use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

A possible solution:

```
mounted () {
    this.noneChangedResults = {...this.results};
}
```

A example *look at the console ;D* :

```js
// Without spread operator

a = {}
console.log('a', a)
b = {}
console.log('b', b)
b.c = 3
console.log('b', b)
a = b
console.log('a', a)
b.d = 4
console.log('b', b)
console.log('a', a)

// With spread operator

a = {}
console.log('a', a)
b = {}
console.log('b', b)
b.c = 3
console.log('b', b)
a = {...b}
console.log('a', a)
b.d = 4
console.log('b', b)
console.log('a', a)
```

Comment: This didn't work.

When I view the object in the console it has this:

`get changed:ƒ reactiveGetter()` and `get changed:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)` maybe i need to change this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone `this.results` in `this.noneChangedResults` with `Object.assign`:

```
this.noneChangedResults = Object.assign({}, this.results)
```

Simply assigning an object to another will reflect the changes to the first object:

```
let a = {a: 1}

let b = a

b.a = 2

console.log(a) // Output: {a: 2}
```

But using `Object.assign` will make a copy of the first object so the changes to the second object won't affect the first object:

```
let a = {a: 1}

let b = Object.assign({}, a)

b.a = 2

console.log(a) // Output: {a: 1}
```

Comment: This didn't work. When I view the object in the console it has this: get `changed:ƒ reactiveGetter()` and `get changed:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)` maybe i need to change this ?

Comment: No I had no errors. I have managed to solve it, so its not a problem thanks any ways.